# How to move NavLink to the right side in AppBar?

Tags: material-ui

```
<AppBar position="static" className={this.props.classes.appBar}>
<Toolbar
  style={{
    margin: "0 auto",
    width: "80%"
  }}
>
  <Link to="/">
    <img src={logo} alt="logo" width="65" height="48" />
  </Link>

    <NavLink
      to="/about"
      className={this.props.classes.link}
      activeClassName={this.props.classes.activeMenu}
    >
```

How can I move `NavLink` to the right side? I tried with `edge`, but it does not work. It is only for `ImageButton` available.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

One approach is to use a Grid container and wrap your components in Grid item as follows

```js
<AppBar position="static">
  <Toolbar
    style={{
      margin: "0 auto",
      width: "80%"
    }}
  >
    <Grid direction="row" justify="space-between" alignItems="center" container>
      <Grid item>
        <Link to="/">
           <img src={logo} alt="logo" width="65" height="48" />
        </Link>
      </Grid>
      <Grid item>
        <NavLink
            to="/about"
            className={this.props.classes.link}
            activeClassName={this.props.classes.activeMenu}
        >
          // the rest of the code goes here
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>;
```

The `Grid` component uses flex and can be configured to work as you need, in your case `justify` is set to `space-between` than means that the elements will be pushed to the margin of the container and separated by the space between them.

More on `Grid` and aligning items can be found in the documentation [HERE](https://material-ui.com/components/grid/)